# Running two copies of Apache web server on same server for two different applications

Tags: apache, web, server

I've created another instance of Tomcat(port: 81) to run a different application in a server. Tomcat is running successfully but I want to run apache web server on top of it. So, I copied existing apache in another folder and configured to the another instance of tomcat. I'm facing below error. Your help will be greatly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJrCG.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste your settings into your question.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that both instances are configured to also listen for https connections on the default port (443), i.e. while you may have configured them to listen on different http ports (i.e. 80 and 81), you haven't done the same for https.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I removed 81 port and deployed the second application in same tomcat webapps folder. Please assist how to host the second application on 443 port, I need give this configuration in my apache httpd.exe, below is the current config set for existing application. ServerName example1.com:80

Answer (score 0):

First, something else is already using that 443 port, so try 8443.

Also, technically, you can install Tomcat twice using different service names, but why. The beauty of Tomcat is using one installation for multiple applications.

Tomcat is intended to support multiple apps. With a .war file you simply upload your .war file to web apps folder. Tomcat will automatically extract the war file.

To run app as ROOT application, delete the ROOT folder in Tomcat. Rename the .war file for the app you want to install to ROOT.war, it will extract to ROOT folder and you will access it from http://servername:8080, if you kept the default settings of the tomcat connector.

Now, to add a second application, copy a .war file to Tomcat webapps folder, with a different name other than ROOT.war, such as example.war. It will automatically extract the .war file into an example folder. To access that application, go to http://servername:8080/example. You will not have two Tomcat connectors for port 8080, just the 1, and you will access non-ROOT webapps via a context path.

Option 1:

If you want to use TLS in Tomcat, you need to uncomment the 8443 connector in Server.xml. You also need to create a keystore, and put in that keystore information in Server.xml to allow TLS.

Option 2(Doesn’t work with option 1, unless you pick a different port):

If you want a web server with TLS, then set Apache Web Server to listen on 8443, which will also require creating a key store and virtual host file in Apache Tomcat, but leave the Tomcat port at 8080 as it normally would be. Then use virtual host settings on Apache Web Server to proxy to the Tomcat apps (jumping from 8443 to the 8080 ports on the same host with Tomcat only listening on 127.0.0.1 or different hosts with proper network separation so people can’t get around the Web Server). Apache2 would be listening at the Web
Server FQDN.

Example:

1. Skip the Apache Web Server, and use different context path settings (as needed) for each tomcat application on the single 8443 port. (Make sure Apache2 is no longer using 8443).

ROOT app:

User—>https://servername:8443

App2:

User—>https://servername:8443/app2

2. Using Apache Web Server, you would proxy from port 8443 to 8080. Apache Web Server listening on 8443, Tomcat listening on 8080. TLS encryption would be at the Web Server. The connection between the Apache2 and Tomcat would be unencrypted on the same server.

This is a pretty thorough example of reverse proxy:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

User—>https://servername:8443–>http://localhost:8080

Comment: Thanks for answering, for an existing application, I'm using apache webserver on top on my tomcat. Now I need to host a different application on same 80 port, so as you said deployed the .war file of second application in my tomcat and I've added domain name for the second application(example2.com) in same apache httpd.exe config file as shown below, but domain name is not recognizing.  Please assist!                                      ServerName example1.com:80        ServerName example2.com:80

Comment: Without getting into more DNS stuff and how DNS works, Domain name would be your server name if you are only accessing it in LAN. You need your own domain name and static ip or dynamic dns with firewall rules if you want to access it from the public internet.

Comment: I need to have Apache web server configured for second application also, So in my httpd.exe file, I've given the following configuration: ServerName: example1.com ServerName example2.com where example1 is already in place with its own SSL certs, I've added the example2.com part, but when try to  access the 2nd application with example2.com, example1.com application is opening. Please assist!

Comment: Use a virtual host file, like this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html